# Need a solution for this scenario of updating tables in my database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a windows form application, the UI elements in my form are filled from a table in my sql server database.The records are added to the table through some Loaders(thru code) by reading from some other source. Now the user can update the values through the UI, which in turn updates the table in my DB.

Here is my problem, Loaders are run frequently. The source cannot be updated with my changes. When they run the loader, i will lose all the udpates made. Whats the best way to avoid this? I have 2 solutions.

1. Keep the values in a new table. Update the table after running loaders with the values from new table.
2. Somehow loaders has to be informed, to avoid overwriting the updated values in my table.

I am not happy with the first approach as its a two step process. Can somebody help with a more efficient solution?
Let me know if i am not clear in describing my problem.
Thanks

Comment: Why loader is run frequently? Pass updated (new or edited) record in DataTable to DB to update. Don't need to call Loader. Just make sure data in DataTable and DB are the same.

Comment: There are several other updates that has to go into the table which is computed by taking data from several other tables. So running loaders is a must in our case

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917674.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171845.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about having an log table feed with a trigger  on update then you can either use a view to match data or update the table after load runs or create a 3rd table... depending of your needs.